# Are there achievements that only can be reached in normal mode?

Tags: achievements, diablo-iii

Can I skip normal mode and head right into Nightmare once I reach level 10, or are there some achievements that can only be done while playing on the lowest difficulty?

Normal is not much of a challenge and I would rather get the better loot from higher difficulties, but I also dont want to miss out on any achievements.

Comment: pretty sure you need to finish all acts in normal to go to nightmare...

Comment: Don't worry, it starts getting harder even on Normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difficulty is not (directly) tied to level, but rather Act completion. You can't go around in Nightmare mode until you've beaten all of Normal mode.

And what's more, you can go back at any time, so even if there are normal-mode specific achievements, you won't lock yourself out of them by rushing to Nightmare.

Comment: Also, like the previous games, difficulty is scaled to the average level you'll be at when you start it...so you'd probably get steamrolled at level 10 in Nightmare, even if you could do it.

Comment: Lowest level monsters in Act 1 Nightmare are 30 or so, needless to say a level 10 character will explode hilariously trying to take them on.